# android notification remoteviews not show

Tags: java, android

i have my code bellow . when the code execute , the notifaction will show , but the remote view will not shown .

i mean i can't see R.layout.layout_update_bar in the notifaction .

```
mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.close_icon,"Pet Parrot", System.currentTimeMillis());
mNotification.defaults = 4;

mRemoteView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_update_bar);
mNotification.contentView = mRemoteView;
mNotification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progress,100,44,false);
mNotification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Siddharth" + "2km -> 20km");
//mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
CharSequence contentTitle = "download";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,PhotoSaSa.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
    .getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle,"", contentIntent);

mNotifyManager.notify(1, mNotification);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setLatestEventInfo()` overwrites your custom `contentView`. Move it to line 3, or better yet, switch to the [`Notification.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) api.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set notification.icon in you code .only set notification.contentView is not success to see it in notification.